# VBA Code in Excel to Substitue

Tags: excel, vba

I know this should be simple but i cannot get it to work.

In a particular range of cells, E15:E30 for example, whenever a person types a comma i want excel to substitute the , with a +

What should my VBA code look like?

Thanks

Comment: I don't believe you can do it "when" you type using VBA.  But you can do it "after" you type and enter the data into the cell by using worksheet_change code.

Answer (score 0):

Place this block of code in the Worksheet code page you want it to be active on in the VBA editor.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    If Not Intersect(Range("E15:E30"), Target) Is Nothing And Target.Cells.Count = 1 Then
        Target.Replace ",", "+"
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: If the user enters '4,3' into a cell in the range, but has previously used Find or Replace selecting "match entire cell contents" as an option, your routine will not replace the comma.  You need to ensure that the options are set the way you need them to be, in case the OP expected the comma to be only a part of what was typed into the cell.  And you should consider whether you want to set that option back to the way it was, after you use it.